Driver Expression - Rotational Difference Threshold
Little confused on how this works, my appologies.
The need for the Driver Expression to work:

Achieve a rotational difference with a threshold of 30 degrees [for effect].
Allow the difference to still calculate even if bones or parenting objects are involved outside of the driver. Like a way for the difference to calculate regardlessly. No clue if python is required outside of the driver for this to work, though? I'm bit of a novice.

Here's the Scripted Expression of the two versions needing change:
max(0.0, 1.0 - abs(((var0 - var1 + math.pi) % (2 * math.pi)) - math.pi) / math.radians(30))

The second is a piecewise function to have control of the speed of the value [0.0 - 1.0 in this example, with a fast-slow-fast pacing effect]:
min(1.0, max(0.0, 0.3 * (raw/0.3)**2 if raw < 0.3 else (0.3 + (raw - 0.3)*1.5 if raw < 0.7 else 0.7 + 0.3*((raw - 0.7)/0.3)**0.5))) where raw = 1 - abs(((rot_A - rot_B + math.pi) % (2 * math.pi) - math.pi) / math.radians(30))

Issue: It seems to me that it's not working or reading the expression to show any results. Any ideas on what I'm missing so far? Is the math not mathing right? Or is this overthinking something super simple to achieve?
